# is there a easy way to use BroadcastChannel with typed Message instead o any?

Tags: typescript, broadcast, channel

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('foo');

channel.postMessage(<any>);
```

I know that there is a library for that (https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel#create-a-typed-channel-in-typescript), but I don't want to include any extra dependency, I just want to let typescript check the types of the messages in compile time

```
import { BroadcastChannel } from 'broadcast-channel';
declare type Message = {
  foo: string;
};
const channel: BroadcastChannel<Message> = new BroadcastChannel('foobar');
channel.postMessage({
  foo: 'bar'
});
```

Comment: Do you want to implement same function but without using `broadcast-channel` ?  Smth like [this](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe)

Comment: I want to use broadcastchannel not let me send or receive "any", but a concrete user defined type... perhaps it is not possible.... may be somehow wrapping the object or so

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom class that extends the native `BroadcastChannel`, making the `postMessage` method stictly typed:

```
export class StrictBroadcastChannel<
  MessageType extends Record<string, any>,
> extends BroadcastChannel {
  public postMessage(message: MessageType): void {
    return super.postMessage(message)
  }
}
```

The usage:

```
type MessageType =
 | { type: 'hello', user: string }
 | { type: 'goodbye' }

const channel = new StrictBroadcastChannel<MessageType>()

channel.postMessage({ type: 'hello' }) // TypeError: missing "user"
channel.postMessage({ type: 'goodbye' }) // OK
```

You can go from here as complex as you like. I embed the message structure into the class itself, so all messages have the `{ type: string, payload?: unknown }` shape, and then I create a message map like so:

```
interface DataMessageMap {
  DATA_START(clientId: string): void
  DATA_CHUNK(chunk: string): void
  DATA_END(): void
}
```